# Downloaded Rtools 4.2 and 4.3 and keep getting error message. What step am I missing?

Tags: r, rstudio, rtools

I've downloaded both versions 4.2 and 4.3 of Rtools but keep getting this error message.

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/gorge/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/prophet_1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1319585 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB
```

I've ran the session using all or one of these lines

```
PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}/usr/bin;${PATH}"
```

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

```
r = getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
options(repos = r)
```

But continue to get an error message. Am I missing a step? I'm new to R and can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: You don't have RTools installed. Google how to install it. If you don't have it installed, RStudio will be the best way to use R if you are new to it.

Comment: Did you restart R after you updated your .Renviron file?

Comment: So I had restarted the session but had continued to get the error message. I ended up exiting out of the window entirely and reopened R studio and ran the code and it has been fixed! I guess I just needed to "turn it off then on again"